# Swift - how do I create an NSArray of UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsarray, cgpoint

I'm trying to create an `NSArray` of `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>`, to pass to `SKSpriteNode` splinePoints. This question is very similar to this: [Swift SKShapeNode shapeWithSplinePoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659656/swift-skshapenode-shapewithsplinepoints)

I'm asking it though because the answers on that thread don't seem to work. According to one of the answers there I need:

> `NSArray` where the `CGPoint` are wrapped in `NSValue` instances

How do I do this though?

I tried this (suggested here [How to create UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint> Object in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309372/how-to-create-unsafemutablepointercgpoint-object-in-swift) )

`var shapePoints = [CGPoint]()
    // populate with points...
    let p = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&shapePoints) { $0 }
    let node = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: p, count: shapePoints.count)`

This solution seems like it's close, but it's for a single `CGPoint`, rather than an array of `CGPoint`, so it throws this error: `Cannot convert value of type`UnsafeMutablePointer<[CGPoint]>`to expected argument type UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27661029/1187415 to your first referenced Q&A should work.

Comment: Gah, I'm sure that wasn't working before. But yes, `let node = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &shapePoints, count: shapePoints.count)` seems to be working. So the ampersand here is C address pointer? Apologies for dupe question, and thanks.